# Expected one of #, input, filter, output in logstash

Tags: logstash

I am trying to make logstash installation work by simply executing the command given in the documentation to echo back what ever typed.But that gives me the following error.

My command

```
 C:\logstash-1.4.0\bin>logstash.bat agent -e 'input{stdin{}}output{stdout{}}'
```

And the error

```
 Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 1, column 1 (byte 1) aft
 er
 You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
 use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
 to restart a running system."
```

Please help.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am testing with logstash-1.4.0 on linux with this [tutorial](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash).

I think it is possible a bug on this version.

For example, I test this command on both linux and window. Everything is ok on linux. But it will occur your error at window!!

> bin>logstash agent -e 'input{stdin{}}output{stdout{}}'

For my recommendation, you can write your configuration in a file. For example, save `input{stdin{}}output{stdout{}}` to a file call "stdin.conf". Then when you start logstash, don't use `-e` flag, instead use `-f` and specific your configuration file.

> bin>logstash agent -f stdin.conf

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you! But adding that dint make any difference!It gives the same error only!

Comment: It is ok to me with this configuration: 'input{stdin{}}output{stdout{}}'

Comment: Is there any other configuration needed before running this command?Other than setting the java_home variable?

Comment: I run this on linux : java -jar logstash-1.3.3-flatjar.jar agent -e 'input{stdin{}}output{stdout{}}'

Comment: oh..you run on logstash-1.3.3..! But I am on 1.4.0!!

Comment: I have update the answer. Logstash 1.4 have large modification. The version before only is a jar file but start from 1.4, it has multiple folder.

Comment: Doing so results in an error showing "Error: No config files found: C:\logstash-1.4.0\lib\logstash\config\test.conf
Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file?
You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
to restart a running system."

Comment: You must save your stdin.conf in the path where you run logstash. For example, if you run logstash in bin/, you must save it in bin directory.

Comment: yeahh..i got it worked when i moved that into a different path! Thanks a lot friend! You made ma day!

Comment: OK. Welcome to logstash. :) ##  I have found your error when i give a absolute path of stdin.conf after -f. But after use relative path there is no any error.

Comment: I mean this error:  "Error: No config files found: C:\logstash-1.4.0\lib\logstash\config\test.conf Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file? You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose to restart a running system."   ## I think it have bug about -e on window platform.

Comment: I got that error when i tried it by specifyng the file name.I moved the config file alone to a diffrent directory and executed,then it got wrkd!

Answer (score 3):

Try without quotes

```
C:\logstash-1.4.0\bin>logstash.bat agent -e input{stdin{}}output{stdout{}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I run `-e` with `--debug`. I have to remove `-e`. Example:

```
GEM_HOME="/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/" /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0/bin/java -server -Xms765M -Xmx2297M -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/logstash/forwarder/tmp/ -Xmx2297M -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -jar /opt/logstash/forwarder/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar -I/opt/logstash/forwarder/lib /opt/logstash/forwarder/lib/logstash/runner.rb agent -f /opt/logstash/forwarder/etc/conf.d/ -l /opt/logstash/forwarder/log/logstash.log -w 1 --debug
```