# Cannot run logstash 1.4.0 in windows 8

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

For one month I am using logstash, so I am still learning basics about it, and also elasticsearch and kibana. Yesterday, I tried to install and start using the new version "logstash 1.4.0". To do this, I follow this [link](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash) , but when I try to run logstash with the following command :

> `bin\logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'`

I get this error :

> “bin” is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The output is as follows:

```
No such command "-e"
Usage: logstash <command> [command args]
Run a command with the --help flag to see the arguments.
For example: logstash agent --help

Available commands:

agent - runs the logstash agent
version - emits version info about this logstash
web - runs the logstash web ui (called Kibana)
rspec - runs tests
```

For information, when I run java-version, I get this :

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)**
```

Comment: If my answer doesn't answer your question could you respond with more details otherwise please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 12):

Well, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629795/expected-one-of-input-filter-output-in-logstash/22632039#22632039). The logstash 1.4.0 have some problem about the command.

For my suggestion, please save the `input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }` to a file call `stdin.conf`. 
Then use the following command to run logstash:

> `bin\logstash agent -f stdin.conf`

You must put the stdin.conf file in the directory where you run logstash

Answer (score 3):

I was unsuccessful running Logstash on Windows, as well, and quickly learned that you must create a, or many, configuration file(s) and run, within "bin", where logstash is stored and where your config file should be saved:

```
logstash agent -f yourConfigFile.txt
```

I created the basic config file as a test as config.txt:

```
input { stdin { } }
output { stdout { } }
```

This takes in data from the prompt and outputs the data to the prompt, as well, as the configuration states (and is probably known. ;-) ), and, of course, Ctrl + C to close the pipeline.

I was able to successfully use a "dynamic" .txt as an input to Logstash, as well as get Elasticsearch and Kibana up and running on localhost.  I have set up a grok filter and have been able to parse the data accordingly with different Kibana dashboards up and running, too.

Unfortunately, I'm still learning a lot about all of the different items that this package can offer to us all, but feel free to ask anything and I'll be more than happy to help if I can!

Comment: Ok thanks, since my post, I also had the chance to learn a lot on the logstash/elasticsearch/kibana trio,so you can also ask me questions if you need.

Comment: Wonderful!  You wouldn't happen to have worked with the email output, have you?  I am trying to configure Logstash to allow for alert emails to be sent based on conditionals but I am having trouble with the "options".  At least that's where I believe my problem lies.

Comment: I ran by this post, and I wanted to update my statement on June 4th.  I was able to configure the config file to allow emails to be sent through SMTP based on conditional statements.  Again, please feel free to ask me if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the `logstash.bat` file that comes with latest logstash does not work quite the way the Unix version does, so the tutorial commands may change.  I think you will have better luck following the cookbook recipe for launching as a service: http://cookbook.logstash.net/recipes/windows-service/. 
You can run from the command line by entering the java command listed in the sample batch file provided.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am not sure about the resolution to my problem, because in the example provided, we are launching a jar, so we use the java command. But now, with the new version, we are launching a bin\logstash. The launching is OK, but he is not finding the command e. There is no jar for the new version I think, so instead of using the new one, I must go back to the previous version?

Comment: Include the -e options in a separate `logstash.conf` file as is done in the example.