# Logstash : Couldn't find any input plugin named 'stdin'

Tags: logstash

I was trying to getting started with logstash. I just downloaded logstash latest version (1.5.3) and try to start with simple configuration, but I am getting following error.

I have done the same thing with logstash-1.4.2, and everything is working fine.

what should I do to make it working?

---

Trace:

```
E:\log tools\logstash-1.5.2\bin>logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }'

    io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
    The error reported is:
      Couldn't find any input plugin named 'stdin'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the stdin input plugin resulted in this error: no suc
    h file to load -- concurrent/atomic_reference/concurrent_update_error
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629795/expected-one-of-input-filter-output-in-logstash/22632039#22632039) you can see that you need to put the configuration in a config file because there was a problem with logstash 1.4 and it seems that there is the same problem in the logstash 1.5

Comment: I have tried with config file, the result was same. 1.4 is working fine, but I can not use 1.5.*